Unity 3D- How to continually measure the distance between two calipers- one is stationary and the other can be moved using up and down arrow keys
I instantiate two cube objects to act as a caliper measuring device in a PI script
public void InstantiateCalipersAtDistance()
    {
        if (headCamera != null)
        {
            float heightInMeters = participantHeightCm / 100f;
            float distance = heightInMeters; // Distance in front of the participant
            Vector3 headPosition = headCamera.transform.position; // Get the head camera position
            Vector3 forward = transform.forward;

            Vector3 baseCaliperPosition = headPosition + forward * distance;
            caliperSeparationDistance = Random.Range(0.05f, 0.25f); // Random distance between 0.05 and 0.25 meters

            baseCaliper = Instantiate(baseCaliperPrefab, baseCaliperPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            movingCaliper = Instantiate(movingCaliperPrefab, baseCaliperPosition + new Vector3(0, caliperSeparationDistance, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Head camera is not assigned.");
        }
    }

The top caliper can be moved up and down but the base caliper stays put in a CC script
 void Update()
    {
        if (canMoveUp)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                transform.Translate(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

            }
        }
        if (canMoveDown)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            {
                transform.Translate(0, -speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

            }
        }
        
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "BaseCaliper(Clone)")
        {
            canMoveDown = false;


        }

    }
    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "BaseCaliper(Clone)")
        {
            canMoveDown = true;


        }

    }

I want to record the distance between the calipers continuously, even when the top one is moving. I tried to do this with a script I got from elsewhere, which I put on the moving (top) caliper object with the Obj field in the inspector having the bottom caliper assigned to it[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/A211jBW8.png).
using UnityEngine;

public class LiveDistanceBetweenCalipers : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] public GameObject obj; // Reference to the other caliper (base caliper)

    public float yDistanceBetweenObjects; // Variable to store the Y distance

    private void Update()
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            // Calculate the Y distance between this object (moving caliper) and the other object (base caliper)
            yDistanceBetweenObjects = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - obj.transform.position.y);

            // Print the Y distance to the console
            Debug.Log("Y Distance between calipers: " + yDistanceBetweenObjects);

            // Optionally, draw a line between the objects for visualization
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, obj.transform.position, Color.green);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Reference to the other caliper (base caliper) is missing.");
        }
    }

  
}

It seems to continually track a distance but I am pretty sure it is wrong as the line points to a different position in the scene form the top caliper, and the numbers I get don't make sense relative to the distance.
The uploaded screenshots hopefully make what I want to to more understandable if anyone can offer an assist.
Screenshot of BaseCaliper root enter image description here MovingCaliper inspector enter image description here
Script attcehd to moving caliper 

Are you sure your one prefab doesn't maybe have a weird offset between it's root and the actual visuals?

alternatively ensure you have this component attached to the correct object and referenced the correct other object .. besides that I don't see much that should go wrong

I don't think I have any offset on its root, maybe I haven't got all the right options ticked but it seems to be normal as far as I can tell- Ill try upload an image of the prefab inspector for both calipers

So which one has your LiveDistanceBetweenCalipers script attached?

Moving caliper (additional picture uploaded)

Just to be sure .. the BaseCaliper referenced there via the Inspector .. is that a prefab asset or the actual instance in your scene? Ensure it is really the scene instance (single click on it in the Inspector should highlight the according object) .. otherwise you of course all the time use the position of the prefab which was never set and will just stay whatever the values say there

Yes it is the actual asset. I have actually managed to find a solution and will post here today or tomorrow before marking as solved.

well as said ... it should not be the actual asset because that one never ever moves ... you want to rather reference there the existing instance from your Scene!

Your issue seems to be that in the Inspector of LiveDistanceBetweenCalipers in the obj field you referenced the PREFAB ASSET BaseCalipher.
This prefab only lives in the assets folder and of course will never move at all and have no runtime behavior.
You rather want to have a reference to the actual existing INSTANCE which is currently living in your scene!
You should probably be assigning it right here
baseCaliper = Instantiate(baseCaliperPrefab, baseCaliperPosition, Quaternion.identity);
movingCaliper = Instantiate(movingCaliperPrefab, baseCaliperPosition + new Vector3(0, caliperSeparationDistance, 0), Quaternion.identity);

// assign the correct target reference
movingCalipher.GetComponent<LiveDistanceBetweenCalipers>().obj = baseCalipher;


Thanks, yes that may have been the reason although I have now solved it by making a parent caliper object and assigning the two prefabs as its children (I think they are no longer prefabs once this happens?).
I have a DistanceToCheckpoint script taken from this tutorial on the moving caliper
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tg2M35CVP4E&t=1s
and have modified my code in other places to make it work which it now does.
If this is enough information on how it is solved, I will mark as solved as the base code is from that tutorial.

@MrAwesome the things returned from Instantiate are no prefabs anymore. You don't really need the additional parent in the hierarchy if you just make sure to assign the instance to the field ... but if you go with a single master prefab with both objects included as children it is as valid. In that case this entire prefab instance is a in itself referenced scene instance so either way is fine
